# Minimizing inside a spherical uncertainty region

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to figure out how to solve:

$\min_U r_{p}$

where $r_{p}=\alpha^\intercal\omega$ and  $U$ is a sphere centered at $\alpha$ with radius equal to $\chi|\alpha|$ . ( $\omega$ is a vector or weights and $\chi$ lies between 0 and 1.)

The authors end up with the following solution:

$\min_U r_{p}=\alpha^\intercal\omega-\chi|\alpha||\omega|$

The authors hint at Bayesian estimation but I am not familiar with it.
Any ideas as to how they may have arrived at this would be great.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What is fixed and what are the decision variables?  All of the variables you mention end up in the solution so these cannot have been optimized out.

Comment: Hi Noah. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

We are letting $\alpha$ lie in an uncertainty region given by the sphere described above. $\omega$ is fixed.

If you would like to understand this better, please have a look at the paper on this link:  http://ssrn.com/abstract=1483412 (specifically page 6.)

